# N-level tree structure in android implementation

Tags: tree-structure

I want to implement a N-level tree structure in android. I have gone through the ExpandableListView, but it is applicable for only 2 or 3 levels. My requirement is as below...

```
CAR
|
|==Toyota
|     |
|     |==Sedan
|     |     |
|     |     |==Camry
|     |     |    |
|     |     |    |==Manufacture year
|     |     |    |==Body Colour
|     |     |    |    |
|     |     |    |    |==Black
|     |     |    |    |==Blue
|     |     |    |    |==Red
|     |     |    |    
|     |     |    |==Alloy Wheels
|     |     |    |==CD player
|     |     |    |==Petrol/Diesel
|     |     |    
|     |     |==Yaris
|     |          |
|     |          |==Manufacture year
|     |          |==Body Colour
|     |          |    |
|     |          |    |==Black
|     |          |    |==Blue
|     |          |    |==Red
|     |          |    
|     |          |==Alloy Wheels
|     |          |==CD player
|     |          |==Petrol/Diesel
|     |
|     |==Hatch Pack
|     |     |
|     |     |==Yaris
|     |          |
|     |          |==Manufacture year
|     |          |==Body Colour
|     |          |    |
|     |          |    |==Black
|     |          |    |==Blue
|     |          |    |==Red
|     |          |    
|     |          |==Alloy Wheels
|     |          |==CD player
|     |          |==Petrol/Diesel
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |==Four Wheel Drive
|
|
|==Mazda
|
|    This section will have
|    same classification as above
|
|==Nissan
|
|    This section will have
|    same classification as above
|
|==Ferrari
|
|    This section will have
|    same classification as above
|
|==Hyundai
|
|    This section will have
|    same classification as above
|
```

Do you ppl have any suggestions to implement this in Android. A sample code would be more helpful. Thanks in advance.